# How to fix import/export babel-eslint without configuration file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, babeljs, package.json

When I hit npm start, I have the following error:

```
Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level
```

When I looked into this error, they said I need to update eslint configuration file and in parser options put true and all. But, I do not have eslint config file and my package json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.6.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
    "material-icons-react": "^1.0.4",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1",
    "truffle-contract": "^4.0.0-beta.1",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.36"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Update:
the whole error:

```
./src/App.js
  Line 131:  Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

  129 |     );
  130 | 
> 131 |   export default App;
      |   ^
  132 | 
  133 |       <div id="dashboard">
  134 |         <div className="menu">
```

Link to my App.js code:

[my app.js github code link](https://github.com/AdenSTL/stackoverflow-errors/blob/master/App.js)

Update error 2:

```
./src/Article.js
  Line 11:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

   9 |       return (
  10 |         {/* sorting articles by score */}
> 11 |         articles.sort(function (a, b) {
     |         ^
  12 |           return a.score - b.score;
  13 |         });
  14 |
```

[my Article.js github code](https://github.com/AdenSTL/stackoverflow-errors/blob/master/Article.js)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use `import` or `export` inside a function somewhere instead of at the module level. Does the error give you any more information, maybe filename and line number for the parsing error?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my question and posted the whole error.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you're trying to call `export default App` from inside `render`, you should move that line outside the component (to the bottom of the file). If that doesn't help, it would help if you posted the code for the whole component.

Comment: Yes, i have updated my question and added github code link to App.js file,please review it.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import` and `export` statements cannot be inside a function or class definition, they have to be at the module level.

```
import something from './file'; // <-- module level, outside function

function App() {
  export default App; // <-- inside function, this will break everything
  return <div>Hello</div>
}

export default App // <-- module level, outside function
```

The error is pretty clear: you have an extra `export` statement in the middle of your `render` method.

It looks like you have some duplicated code `render`. Remove these lines: https://github.com/AdenSTL/stackoverflow-errors/blob/master/App.js#L131-L153

so that `render` looks like this:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <AppBar position="static">
        <div id="dashboard">
          <div className="menu">
            <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>
              <NavLink exact to="/CardStack">
                Home
              </NavLink>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>
              <NavLink exact to="/Article" >
                Article
              </NavLink>
            </MenuItem>
          </div>
          <div className="content">
            <Route exact path="/CardStack" component={CardStack} />
            <Route exact path="/Article" component={Article} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </AppBar>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I still get error which i have updated in the question error 2 and with github code link to the file.Please, look into it. Thanks.

Comment: That error is unrelated to your original question, which now seems to be resolved. You should try to work it out on your own (based on the error message), then if you can't solve it post a new question explaining what you've tried.

Comment: Thank you. Please check out the new question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56591097/how-to-fix-parsing-error-unexpected-token